# I want to allow an IP range in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to allow all IP Addresses between `145.050.039.008` and `145.050.039.017` inclusive

For example (but this doesn't work):

```
allow from 145.050.039.008 145.050.039.017
```

or:

```
allow from 145.050.039.008,145.050.039.017
```

or:

```
allow from 145.050.039.008/017
```

?

Thanks,
Jelmar

Comment: I feel this would have been a valuable question.

Comment: Not linked with the problem, but I'd suggest avoiding leading zeroes in IP addresses.
See http://superuser.com/questions/857603/are-ip-addresses-with-and-without-leading-zeroes-the-same

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
A̶l̶l̶o̶w̶ ̶f̶r̶o̶m̶ ̶1̶4̶5̶.̶0̶5̶0̶.̶0̶3̶9̶.̶0̶0̶8̶ ̶1̶4̶5̶.̶0̶5̶0̶.̶0̶3̶9̶.̶0̶1̶7̶
```

C̶h̶e̶c̶k̶ ̶[h̶e̶r̶e̶](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow) ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶d̶e̶t̶a̶i̶l̶s̶.̶

---

**(late) EDIT:**

My bad, my previous answer never worked, at this time I answered without really understanding the problem.

### Option #1: define all IP

Here's the only way to do it:

```
Allow from 145.50.39.8
Allow from 145.50.39.9
Allow from 145.50.39.10
Allow from 145.50.39.11
Allow from 145.50.39.12
Allow from 145.50.39.13
Allow from 145.50.39.14
Allow from 145.50.39.15
Allow from 145.50.39.16
Allow from 145.50.39.17
```

### Option #2: use a partial IP

If you want something more generic, you can use a partial IP:

```
Allow from 145.50.39
```

But this will allow IP from `145.50.39.0` to `145.50.39.255`.

### Option #3: use a netmask or a CIDR

To get even closer, you can use a netmask or a CIDR:

```
Allow from 145.50.39.0/255.255.255.224
```

or

```
Allow from 145.50.39.0/27
```

This will allow IP from `145.50.39.0` to `145.50.39.31`.

Comment: Your solution only allows 145.050.039.008 and 145.050.039.017. Not what is in between.

Comment: I did put effort in my search, which is got confused with different solutions proposed. No reason to downmod. This has just always been quite difficult for me to understand and I needed some finality on it.

Comment: And apparently, according to Gerben, your answer samsamX is not even right. Can anyone help me with this? It is about a range, not a sequence

Comment: @Jelmar you can always uncheck your answer. Never pick an answer that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: `Allow from 145.50.39.0/27` and `This will allow IP from 145.50.39.0 to 145.50.39.31.`... Can someone explain this? To me it would seem logical it'd accept `145.50.39.0` to `145.50.39.27`

Comment: This is not a range, but a net mask, acting at a binary level: `/27` means "27 bits 1, then only 0". In other words, it means `145.50.39.0 & 11111111.11111111.11111111.11100000`, or `10010001.00110010.00100111.00000000 & 11111111.11111111.11111111.11100000`. This means everything but the five last bits are "locked", and the highest number you'll be able to get with 5 bits is `11111` : `31`.

Comment: [Apache 2.4 docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) say `Allow` is now depreciated.